# Android-OpenCV Warp ROI

Tags: android, opencv, zooming, roi, warp

How can I warp a rectangular extracted ROI so that it fills the entire preview keeping proportions?
I extracted a rectangular from the camera source image (Opencv Mat) and I saved into another Mat. Now I'd like to warp/zoom/enlarge/I don't know ... it so that it fills the entire preview keeping proportions! Obviously to fills preview it might needs to become larger than preview size .. don't care!

Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at opencv functions warpPerspective and findHomography. There are a lot of questions with those on stackoverflow and google.